# Using "across" after preposition "to"?

Tags: differences, prepositions

English is not my first language, and I often lose my confidence when I use **across** in my sentence.

Could you please give me an advice on the sentence that I have written below?

> Health education is so important that it should be provided **across** all the students.

My mind keeps telling me the sentence should be

> Health education is so important that it should be provided **to
>   across** all the students.

Can we use two prepositions one after another?

Comment: You **don't** need a preposition there.

Comment: Please see also [ell.se]

Comment: Thanks Kris, I appreciate it. Should I move this post to ELL website? This is my second post, and I'm quite confused about what kind of questions I can ask in this website.

Comment: Hi, Sungwoo. Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your question reads more like a **proof-reading** request and it is off-topic. Did you try to look up **across** and **provide** in the dictionary? What did you find and what you don't understand from it? Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Hi Rathony, thanks for the reply. Yes I have looked up dictionary on both of those two words, **across** and **provide**. I understand what those mean. However, I am not sure whether "provide to across" is correct or not. Sometimes, I hear people use two prepositions (i.e. I am about to play soccer.)

Comment: What makes you think both **about** and **to** are prepositions? I think you had better ask future questions on English Language Learners as advised by Kris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Words that can be used as prepositions take part in many idiomatic usages in English.  That means that rational analysis won't tell you why they're used as they are; you just have to memorize these usages.  First of all, as you noted, sometimes prepositions double up.  For instance you can say

> I went to the store **with** her

where *with* means accompanying, and you can say

> He drove **along** the highway

where *along* means in a marked direction.  But the two words can act as a unit (called a compound preposition):

> I had to attend physics lectures **along with** laboratory sessions.

Here, *along with* means in addition to.  But the two words don't always act as a unit.  Take the sentence

> She gets **along with** him.

In this case, the word *along* goes with the verb *get* to form what's called a phrasal verb.  *Get along* means to have a good relationship.  The sentence may be analyzed as

> She (gets along) **with** him.

where the parenthesized words make up the verb, and *with* acts alone as a **preposition**.  A further complication is that *along* may act as an adverb (i.e., as a modifier of a verb or adjective).  For instance

> He shuffled **along with** his head down.

In this case *along* is an adverb of manner, telling us how he shuffled, leaving *with* as the preposition.

Comment: Hi, deadrat. I edited the question and please see if they are OK. The OP seems to be confused about **across** more than about the **compound** preposition.

Comment: Wow... I am amazed by your knowledge! I truly appreciate it, Deadrat. Thanks to you too, Rathony, for editing the format.

Comment: @Sungwoo You can accept the answer if you find it helpful by clicking on the check below the downvote mark on the left.

Comment: @Rathony Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

See, you cannot use the phrase **'provide to across'**. its not correct.
Now, coming to your sentence, a better sentence with the same meaning would be- **Health education is so important that it should be provided all across the country.**(as it is 'so important', use of the word 'country' will be better)

However, your sentence is correct in a way, but still doesn't give a good feeling :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Sungwoo i hope its correct then, you may use the word **students** as well..

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to keep the sentence, I think it would be better to say:

"Health education is so important that it should be provided **to** all (of) the students."

"Across" isn't necessary.